# How we can find the sign for trigonometric functions without graph

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

For $\sin(x)$ or $\cos(x)$ etc. how we can show that it is negative on $\left[\pi ,2\pi \right]$ ? without graph?

So if we have $\sin(2x)$ or $\cos(2x)$ how we can find the sign on $\left[0,2\pi \right]$, but don't tell me $\sin(2x)$ gets its negative value like in the interval $\sin(x)$ on $\left[\pi ,2\pi \right]$ it is negative and that's the reason .. Can we prove that with derivative of the function?

Comment: What are the base assumptions that you are allowing for an answer? The fact that $\sin(\cdot )$ is positive for $(0,\pi)$ could be seen as axiomatic as it being negative for $(\pi,2\pi)$. Just wondering what you consider to be 'given'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to learn fundas. For $\sin x $ to be positive $ 0< x < \pi$. For $\cos x $ to be positive, $ -\pi/2 < x < \pi/2.$ For other quadrants they are negative. For $ 2 x $ it is same situation.

Bringing in derivative is next step in learning fundas. The derivative is negative for  reducing functions, another way of saying it is that its derivative is $<0$.

Do not confuse negative value of the main function with the sign of its derivative.

Comment: with derivative we find monotony of main function not negative value of the main function, I've right?

Comment: By monotony you mean positive rate of change of main dependent variable.Yes that is the warning I wanted to sound.